# Serving HTML pages with Go

Tags: html, css, go

I am trying to serve an HTML page with golang API

This is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    
    <body>
      <section>
      <div class="login-box">
    <h2>Login into your account</h2>
    <form method="post" action="/login">
        <label for="name"></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="name" name="name"><br>
        <label for="password"></label>
        <input  type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password"> <br>
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
       
        </div>
      <br>
    <nav class="myNav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Don't have an account?</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="">Sing Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Login with Google Account</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      </section>
     </html>
<style>
  .login-box{
    font-size: large;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
  .login-box input{
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
button{
  width:30%;
  position:absolute;
  left:70%;
  background:none;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 4px;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Courier, monospace;
}

label{
  color:black;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa';
  font-size:30px;
}
body {

  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #23D5AB, #23A6D5,#E73C7E);
    background-size:300% 300%; 
    position:relative;
    animation:change 10s ease-in-out infinite;
}
  @keyframes change{
    0%{
      background-position: 0 50%;
    }
    50%{
      background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100%{
      background-position: 0 50%;
    }
  }
.myNav ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style: none;

}
.myNav >ul {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;

}
ul a{
    display: block;
    padding: .5rem;
    background: #262626;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

 .myNav a:hover,
 .myNav a:focus 
  {
    background:crimson;
  }
 .myNav >ul ul a{
    padding-left: 3rem;
    /*flex-direction: column;*/
  }
@media (min-width: 500px){
  .myNav ul{
    flex-direction:row;
  }

  .myNav >ul ul{
    position:relative;
    display:none;
    transition: .4s ease opacity;
    /*display:none;*/
    
  }
  .myNav >ul>li:hover ul,
  .myNav >ul>li:focus-within ul{
    display:block; 
    position:absolute;
  }
 
  .myNav > li {
    position: relative;
   flex:1; 
  }
  .myNav >ul>li:hover ul,
  .myNav >ul>li:focus-within ul{
    display:block; 
  }

}
  h2{
      font-family: 'Comfortaa';
      font-size:45px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
      
  }
</style>

    </body>
       
 </html>
```

I am serving this html, using golang, with: router.HandleFunc("/", Utilities.LoginPage)

When I try to render the html natively, or on codepen it works but when I serve the file with Go API, the html page doesn't appear same!

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: What does "looks scuffed" mean?

Comment: Things are all over the place. The live background doesn't work.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/TrCFZlg     https://imgur.com/a/fTZ8A71

Comment: Shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: The same as what?

Comment: The same look, it s the same file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To host static files, you can use [net/http File server](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer). You can create a directory within your repository and point your handler using inbuilt http.FileServer. Here is the example:

Assuming we saved above file as `index.html` under the repo `tmp`

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./tmp")))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Comment: woaaaaaaah! now it works!! Thanks man !!! But what if my file isn't called index.html?

Comment: let's say if your file is example.html, you call your endpoint as localhost:8080/example.html